# Auto reply / auto responder for mail?

Tags: server, software-recommendation, email

I am looking for a (freeware) solution for auto reply/out of office reply on my (web)mail. I have done some googling but haven't found anything for this yet.

Does any know what program can do this?

My server runs on Ubuntu 10.04 server. I have root/admin access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more research.

I found that I can use plesk panel, which has an auto-reply feature built in.